# Keeping items together in a HTML div columns layout

Tags: html

I am trying to display an adaptive display of images (svgs) and text in columns, that responds to changes in the window width. What I have below almost does the job but not quite, in that the display at the top of the columns is not what I would wish

1. in the left most column, there is a blank line at the top
2. in the other columns, there are multiple images at the top
3. also I have failed to line up the text with the centre of each image, despite adding a line height to the p element enclosing the text

Please could someone set me straight

```html
 <div style="column-width:230px; column-gap:20px">
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Alarm Sound</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Archive</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Backward/Undo</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;British National Grid</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Buy</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Calendar</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Cancel</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Circle (Shape)</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Clock</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Comment</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Degrees</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Mils</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Points</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Rose</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compress</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Contract Menu</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Copy</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Database</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Dates</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Dates</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decide</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decimal Lat Long</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease Text Size</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Degrees Minutes Seconds</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p line-height:32px">&nbsp;Delete</p>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: `<div>`s should not be immediate children of `<ul>`, use `<li>` instead. I really recommend against using inline styles, you can use the `<style>` tag for learning, if you dont want to split up the file. To achive the layout you're looking for, you could check out [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your HTML, by replacing the divs within ul by li elements. And moving the p element inside the li's. This should be your markup :

```
<div style="column-width:230px; column-gap:20px">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Alarm Sound</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Archive</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Backward/Undo</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;British National Grid</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Buy</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Calendar</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Cancel</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Circle (Shape)</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Clock</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Comment</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compass</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compass Degrees</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compass Mils</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compass Points</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compass Rose</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Compress</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Contract Menu</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Copy</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Database</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Dates</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Dates</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Decide</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Decimal Lat Long</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Decrease Text Size</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Degrees Minutes Seconds</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <svg width="32" height="32">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
      </svg>
      <p>&nbsp;Delete</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of providing styling inline to each element you can write external CSS for this. This should be your CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Please update if you need any further help on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it with away a little bit easier 
1. You can update your HTML, by

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <svg width="32" height="32">
            <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
        </svg>
        <p>&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and with a simple css using flex box u can control with the width of each item by using `flex-base` property

```
.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-basis: 230px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, sir. I've cleaned up your markup a little bit.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  height: 300px; //adjust column height here
  
  padding: 0;
  
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 200px; // adjust column width here
}

ul li:before {
  content: '';
  
  display: block;
  
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  margin-right: 10px;
  
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Advanced</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Advanced</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Alarm Sound</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Archive</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Backward/Undo</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>British National Grid</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Buy</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Calendar</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Cancel</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Circle (Shape)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Clock</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Comment</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compass</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compass Degrees</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compass Mils</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compass Points</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compass Rose</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Compress</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Contract Menu</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Copy</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Database</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Dates</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Dates</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Decide</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Decimal Lat Long</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Decrease</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Decrease</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Decrease Text Size</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Degrees Minutes Seconds</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Delete</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed in your code just you need to add style attribute style="line-height:32px":

```
<div id="txtfrom" style="column-width:230px; column-gap:20px">
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg> </div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Advanced</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg> </div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Advanced</p>
       <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div> <p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Alarm Sound</p> 



    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg> </div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Archive</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Backward/Undo</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;British National Grid</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Buy</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Calendar</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Cancel</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Circle (Shape)</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Clock</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Comment</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Degrees</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Mils</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Points</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compass Rose</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Compress</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Contract Menu</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Copy</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Database</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Dates</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Dates</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decide</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decimal Lat Long</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Decrease Text Size</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Degrees Minutes Seconds</p>
    <div style="float:left"><svg width="32" height="32"><circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" /></svg></div><p style="line-height:32px">&nbsp;Delete</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party, but here is my answer without using flex or ul/li combination. I just made the circle div as the parent div for the circle and span (changed from p to span). Here is the code along with the style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Column SVG</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        div div {
            width: 230px;
        }

        div div svg {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        div div span {
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 32px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="column-width:230px; column-gap:20px;">
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Advanced</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Alarm Sound</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Archive</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Backward/Undo</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;British National Grid</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Buy</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Calendar</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Cancel</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Circle (Shape)</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Clock</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Comment</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compass</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compass Degrees</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compass Mills</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compass Points</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compass Rose</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Compress</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Contract Menu</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Copy</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Database</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Dates</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Dates</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Decimal Lat Long</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Decrease</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Decrease</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Decrease Text Size</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Degrees Minutes Seconds</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <svg width="32" height="32">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" fill="#0000ff" />
            </svg>
            <span>&nbsp;Delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```